# Aligning a view to an ImageView in different resolutions

Tags: android, size, imageview, screen-resolution

The problem with properly handling multiple screen sizes on Android has been talked all over thousands of times. However I couldn't find a solution to m problem. In a nutshell I need to align my custom progress bar over an imageView. I've got 3 set of drawables for the imageView - ldpi(240x400), mdpi(320x480), hdpi(480x800). I align my custom view in Java with the following code:

```
        //get screen density 
       float density = getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

       //set the progress bar position according to screen density
       if ( density == 1.0f)
       {
           ImageView micImage = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewClk));
           Drawable drawing = micImage.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();

            // Get current dimensions
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams((int)(height/13.94), (int)(height/13.94));
            params.setMargins((int)(width/2.30), 0, 0, (int)(height/2.75));

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,R.id.imageViewClk);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,R.id.imageViewClk);
            myCustomTwistedProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
       }else if ( density == 1.5f ){
           ImageView micImage = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewClk));
           Drawable drawing = micImage.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();

            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams((int)Math.round(height/14.13), (int)Math.round(height/14.13));
            params.setMargins((int)Math.round( width/2.27), 0, 0, (int)Math.round(height/2.91));

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,R.id.imageViewClk);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,R.id.imageViewClk);
            myCustomTwistedProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
       }else if ( density == 0.75f ){
           ImageView micImage = ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewClk));
           Drawable drawing = micImage.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)drawing).getBitmap();

            // Get current dimensions
            int width = bitmap.getWidth();
            int height = bitmap.getHeight();

            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams((int)(height/14.88), (int)(height/14.88));
            params.setMargins((int)(width/2.27), 0, 0, (int)(height/2.69));

            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_LEFT,R.id.imageViewClk);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM,R.id.imageViewClk);
            myCustomTwistedProgressBar.setLayoutParams(params);
       }
```

Everything worked fined on different screen sizes however when I tried to check on 480x854 resolution the vertical alignment of the custom view was incorrect. Checked with 480x800 on the same screen size and it again works. I than went for a big jump and checked in GalaxyTab and the horizontal and vertical alignments were wrong. Now my first though was that the bitmap width and height were the one of the image not the actual resized imageview. So I spent a lot of time on trying to get the real size of the imageview and even went for viewTreeObserver but the results were all the same - the correct, unchanged (unscaled?) bitmap size. So being positive that the problem is not here I couldn't get through further. Does anyone have an idea why the alignment is not working correctly?

PS: as for the image view in layout xml file I have 2 configurations for long and notlong but this image has the same description in both:

```
<ImageView 
 android:src="@drawable/cloking" 
 android:id="@+id/imageViewClk"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
 android:layout_above="@+id/imageViewProcess"
 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
 android:cropToPadding="false" 
 android:layout_marginTop="60dp" 
 android:scaleType="fitXY">
</ImageView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Android will scale the image but it will maintain aspect ratio for the image. You can't control aspect ratio with layout settings (as far as I know). I would solve that problem by choosing few screen ratios that I want to support and making few more resources (images that would have aspect ratios that you support). Code would look like this:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
int width = display.getWidth();
int height = display.getHeight();

ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewClk);
if(width/height == aspectRatio1)
{
    image.setImageResource(R.id.imageAspect1);
} else if( width/height == aspectRatio2...
```

Comment: But maintaining the aspect ratio is exactly what I need! Assuming that the image is 237x424 (hdpi version) I know where exactly my custom item should be placed over my image (you see the calculation in the code). However it is correct for 800 but not for 854. There are 2 possibilities I see: either the image is resized but I can't get the 'real' size in pixel(I though that I ruled that one out but not 100% sure), or the image is not resized (it is not necessary cause it fits and dpi resource is right) but the correctly calculated positioning pixels are somehow incorrectly used in the layout...